# How to get starting positions of all substring occurences in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, substr, substring

Is there a ready function to get the array of positions, where a certain substring starts?

For example,

```
$needle = "apple";
$haystack = "one apple two apples three apples";
$r = f($haystack , $needle);
// should give: 
$r = array(4 , 13 , 24);
// i.e. the positions of "a" letters
```

I know that substr_count gives the number of substrings, but how can I get the starting positions?

Thanks for any help !

Answer (score 1):

```
$needle = "apple";
$haystack = "one apple two apples three apples";
$count = preg_match_all(
    '/'.preg_quote($needle).'/', 
    $haystack, $matches, 
    PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE
);
if ($count) {
    var_dump($matches[0]);
}
```

if you have PHP 5.5+, you can use array column to get all the offsets from $matches easily

```
var_dump(array_column($matches[0], 1));
```